# Rails multi-select getting undefined method `to_i'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select multiple `events` in the `invtime` form.

Invtime

```
has_many :events
```

This is my form code:

```
    <%= f.select :event_id, Event.all.collect {|x| [x.title, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

The display looks good!  But, when I select the last event and submit, I get:

```
undefined method `to_i' for ["", "62"]:Array
```

The page inspection shows:

```
<select id="invtime_event_id" multiple="multiple" name="invtime[event_id][]">
  <option value="66">Meeting</option>
  <option value="62">Auto fill some fields on new workorder</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error please? (and eventually the corresponding line raising the error) --- Also, shouldn't you be using `f.select :event_ids` (plural) since it is a multiple select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select helper doesn't know what to do with a collection like that, it assumes the first value is an ID and the second a string, you might be able to just reverse your method calls but this isn't really the right way to create a select tag, instead either use `collection_select` [as dax suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19456868/385532) or [use the `options_from_collection_for_select` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select):

```
<%= f.select :event_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Event.all, :id, :title), {}, :multiple => true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `to_i' for **["", "62"]:Array**

from the docs:

> :include_blank - set to true or a prompt string if the first option element of the select element is a blank. **Useful if there is not a default value required for the select element.**

So try adding `include_blank: true`

```
<%= f.select(:event_id, Event.all.collect {|x| [x.title, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, include_blank: true ) %>
```

also, you might try [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select), where `@events = Event.all`

```
<%= f.collection_select(:event_id, @events, :id, :title, include_blank: true ) %>
```

Comment: Hi dax, I'm pretty sure `include_blank` has nothing to do with this problem, the error comes from trying to convert a blank title to an integer for the select value. Your collection select suggestion is a good one, but there's no need to create extra overhead by adding a temporary variable - just use `Event.all` in the helper itself.

Comment: `include_blank` would fix that, though, right?  If it isn't necessary, you're right, it should be removed - but how does just using `collection_select` remedy that?  There's an object for `x` in OP, otherwise there wouldn't be an `x.id` of 62.  Thanks for your comment!