# How to search with Ransack with multiple items from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ransack

On my events index page, I have a search form that filters the records on the index page based on those search parameters through Ransack.

The search form currently works only when the dance styles and/or event types (both of which are arrays) have one value each, however I would like to be able to search by multiple values of both.

Here's my search form for the dance style and event types fields:

```
 <div class="dancestyle">
                <%= f.label "Dance style", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select(:dance_styles_id_eq, DanceStyle.all.pluck(:name, :id), { :include_blank => "All dance styles" }, { class: "form-select", id: "select-dancestyle", multiple: true, placeholder: "Any dance style" }) %>
            </div>
            <div class="eventtype">
                <%= f.label "Event Type", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select :event_type_id_eq, EventType.all.pluck(:name, :id), { :include_blank => "All event types" }, { id: "select-artist", placeholder: "Any event type", class: "form-select" } %>
            </div>
```

Here's my Event controller index:

```
  def index
    if params[:q]
      params[:q][:combinator] = "and"
      params[:q][:groupings] = []
      split_geo = params[:q][:address_or_city_or_state_or_country_or_continent_cont_all].split(/(,\s)+/)
      split_geo.map! do |a|
        I18n.transliterate a
      end
      split_geo.each_with_index do |word, index|
        params[:q][:groupings][index] = { address_or_city_or_state_or_country_or_continent_cont_all: word }
      end
    end
    @q = Event.ransack(params[:q])
    @events = @q.result(distinct: true)
      .where(event_status_id: 1)
  end
  end
```

Here's the full stack error I'm getting when I set the input fields to allow multiple and search multiple dance styles:

```
14:35:32 web.1  | Started GET "/events?q%5Bname_cont%5D=&q%5Baddress_or_city_or_state_or_country_or_continent_cont_all%5D=&q%5Bdance_styles_id_eq%5D%5B%5D=&q%5Bdance_styles_id_eq%5D%5B%5D=5&q%5Bdance_styles_id_eq%5D%5B%5D=6&q%5Bevent_type_id_eq%5D=&q%5Bevent_month_eq%5D=&q%5Bevent_year_eq%5D=&commit=Search%21" for ::1 at 2022-10-14 14:35:32 -0500
14:35:32 web.1  | Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
14:35:32 web.1  |   Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>"", "address_or_city_or_state_or_country_or_continent_cont_all"=>"", "dance_styles_id_eq"=>["", "5", "6"], "event_type_id_eq"=>"", "event_month_eq"=>"", "event_year_eq"=>""}, "commit"=>"Search!"}
14:35:32 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2335)
14:35:32 web.1  |
14:35:32 web.1  |
14:35:32 web.1  |
14:35:32 web.1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for ["", "5", "6"]:Array
14:35:32 web.1  | Did you mean?  to_s
14:35:32 web.1  |                to_a
14:35:32 web.1  |                to_h):
14:35:32 web.1  |
14:35:32 web.1  | app/controllers/events_controller.rb:38:in `index'
```

How does the `to_i` tie into this? I'm assuming this fix will need to be handled in my events controller.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you mean by *"I would like to be able to search by multiple values of both"*. Right now you are using the `_eq` predicate which as the name suggests is based on equality, maybe you meant `_in` as in `:dance_styles_id_in` and `:event_type_id_in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully up on Ransack but have previously run into this sort of issue (`to_i` being invoked on an `Array` and not an actual `Number`).

I believe this SO Q&A may help you:
[Rails multi-select getting undefined method `to_i'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456757/rails-multi-select-getting-undefined-method-to-i)

As you may be able to tell from reading the above Q&A, the problem *may* be in your form field's name (not sure if that matters to Ransack and am not clear on your app's models, etc.).

See if altering `f.select :dance_styles_id_eq` to `f.select :dance_styles_ids` helps as noted in the linked Q&A. Please note that it may be `f.select :dance_styles_id` as I am not fully up to snuff on Ransack and it's API. If I may oversimplify for a moment, a true Railsy form, would use the plural (`dance_styles_ids`) to reference a `has_many` association.

On other thing to note is that your array of dance style identifiers has an empty string, which you definitely do not want (found in this part of the error message `to_i for ["", "5", "6"]:Array`).

Here's a link to an SO &A on removing blank elements from an array in ruby: [How do I remove blank elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878697/how-do-i-remove-blank-elements-from-an-array)

Hope this can get you started and going in the right direction for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

[Right name](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/search-matches/) of the input is `dance_styles_id_in`. It matches any values in array. But now you use `dance_styles_id_eq`, replace it

And you also send empty string in params. To prevent it use `include_hidden: false` option

```
<%= f.select(:dance_styles_id_in, DanceStyle.all.pluck(:name, :id), { include_blank: "All dance styles", include_hidden: false }, { class: "form-select", id: "select-dancestyle", multiple: true, placeholder: "Any dance style" }) %>
```